# Get the current time

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get current time in ros, because I want to have two dimensional array, one dimension would be int, another
current time, and I want to have function and loop which will go through array, and keep one int value for some exact period of time, for ex. 60sec number will be 100, then next 80sec number will be 80 etc. p.s. sorry for bad tags

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219574/get-the-current-time/) by [commandos23](https://answers.ros.org/users/24676/commandos23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-10-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [wiki/roscpp/Overview/Time  - Getting the Current Time](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time#Getting_the_Current_Time):

> `ros::Time::now()`

> Get the current time as a `ros::Time` instance:

> ```
> ros::Time begin = ros::Time::now();
> ```

via Google: ["ros get current time"](https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr#q=ros+get+current+time)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3